# Knockout observable/viewmodel that can be accessed by other viewmodels?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am building an SPA and everything is going well. It has multiple Viewmodels which are built dynamically and there can be multiple of the same kind, i.e you can open two calculators each having its own model which is bound to a specific div on the page.

Recently I realized that several of the viewmodels were requesting the same data from a web service and on a constant loop every 30 secs - 1 minute. So the same service call was being made multiple times every 30 seconds yet returning the same information.

So what I am trying to figure out is how I can create a "global" observableArray which multiple viewModels can be notified of a change and update rather than doing it themselves, this also helps to make sure the data on the page is consistent.

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
var GlobalData = (function() {
    var commonData = ko.observableArray();
    setInterval(function() {...go get data...commonData(data);}, 30000);
    return {CommonData:commonData}
})();

ko.applyBindings(GlobalData, $('#RandomLonelyDiv')[0]);
```

Then later

```
function Calculator(element){
    function init() { ko.applyBindings(calculator, $(element)[0]); }
    var calculator = {
        CommonData = GlobalData.CommonData
    }
    return calculator;
}
```

If it helps the only reason why I dont have a MainViewModel which contains all my other viewmodels is because i frankly dont know how to set that up for my environment.

I have a AppViewModel which contains a ko.observableArray called Windows, which is contains objects which define the options/information to build certain window types.

```
<!-- ko template:{name:'WindowTemplate', foreach:SelectedTab().Windows} --><!-- /ko -->
```

and then I have a custom Window binding that creates a modified kendoWindow, which creates a new viewmodel of a specific type such as Calculator, and like I said you could have multiple calculators at one time. But when I started this I wasnt really sure how to put that viewmodel into my AppViewModel. Perhaps its just another array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you really need is a "Pub/Sub" model.  That would allow you to publish and subscribe to messages that are ignorant of their generation or destination.  Check out https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js/wiki.

Comment: Very good point. I was hoping to accomplish this using only Knockout but I very well may have to use a separate pub/sub system.

Comment: As a matter of fact Ryan Niemeyer has written a Knockout pub/sub library! http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html And thanks to your answering helped me to find this great piece.

Comment: Glad it helped - I forgot about Ryan's pub/sub, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may be what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/xSKyR/474/

You can subscribe to another viewmodel's observable like so..

```
var ViewModel1 = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.something1 = ko.observable("1");
    self.clickMe = function (data, event) {
        self.something1("2");
    };
};
var ViewModel2 = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.something2 = ko.observable();
    vm1.something1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.something2(newValue);

    });
};
var vm1 = new ViewModel1();
var vm2 = new ViewModel2();
ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById("vm1"));
ko.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById("vm2"));
```